# H2 password issue after Upgrading to Hibernate 5

Tags: java, hibernate, h2, persistence.xml, hbm2ddl

I've just upgraded my project from Hibernate 4.2.8 to Hibernate 5.2.12.Final
The only change in terms of configuration is the persistence provider, instead of `org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence` it's now `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider`.

All of a sudden my Unit Tests which use H2 fail with:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Wrong user name or password [28000-166]
```

Any idea what is causing it?
My H2 configuration in the persistence.xml has not changed:

```
       <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:MyDB;INIT=runscript from 'classpath:/com/camel/database.sql'" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="SA" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />

            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="4" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory" />
        </properties>
```

Comment: Did you try maybe to use `hibernate.connection.username`, `hibernate.connection.password`, `hibernate.connection.url` instead?

Comment: Thanks Michal, I've tried that but still not working.